# Access site every 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I'm begginer in php, and I need your help with the following problem. Let's say for example I have two pages - index.php (where user needs to do some action) and redeem.php (his generated code). Now, here’s how it should work:

- user can do the task only once a day (**?**), if task already been done, then proper message shows up
- after completing the task gets access to redeem.php (✔ - done)
- redeem.php should have some protection if user hasn't voted (✔ - done)

Now.. I don't know how to solve the first point. I could do this based on cookies, but some 'smart' user can simply remove them :/ so this is pointless. I guess the best way to do this is mysql but I have completely no idea how to grab time of completing the task and then work with this, depending on whether the user has done his task today or not. Ok, I hope you understand all of this ;p and expect some good advice from you guys Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Do you want to add some code to the question?

Comment: What do you define as a user? An IP Address? anonymous browser session? A registered user account? Store the time of action in a database, then to compare it, convert it to a timestamp and compare to `time()`. The condition would be something like `if(($lastAction + 24*60*60) < time()) { // allowed }`

Comment: mysql and you need to do some google before posting here.

Comment: if its a registered user, then you can add field in users mysql table like `last_task_access` with timestamp as value, then whenever user trying to access task, you can check it with `( ( time() - $last_task_access ) > 86400 )`

Comment: @bystwn22 Rather than checking for seconds I think he just wants to make sure it's not the same day.

Comment: @MattBusche yeah, but if `( ( time() - $last_task_access ) > 86400 )`  is returning true, he can update the database again with the current timestamp :)  
but anyway, in that case, in my opinion, @Cristian's answer is better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `voting_records` table, with a `user_id` column, and a `vote_datetime` column. To create a new record:

```
INSERT INTO `voting_records` (user_id, vote_datetime) VALUES (123, NOW());
```

To check if a user has voted in the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(NOW(), max(vote_datetime)) < 24*60*60) AS already_voted FROM voting_records WHERE user_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cookies you simply need to save the date of when this particular action will be available.
So you can do something like

```
$expireTime = strtotime("+1 day");
```

With the expire time you can simply check if the current time is major or equal to the expire date:

```
if (time() >= $expireTime) {
    echo "Hey, you already voted!";
} else {
    header("Location: /redeem.php");
    exit;
}
```

Obviously i cannot be more specific without having a piece of code to start.